# Adding values to a array propery of an interface in typescript

Tags: arrays, object, interface

I have the following interface below

export interface ICompany {
id: number,
name: string,
urlName: string,
display: boolean,
selected: boolean,
mainModules: IMainModule[]
}

I have a variable of type interface

CompaniesAndModules: ICompany[]

I tried the below but it has an error. self.modules is of type mainModules

self.CompaniesAndModules.mainModules[].push(self.modules);

export interface IMainModule {
id: number,
name: string,
display: boolean,
selected: boolean,
subModules: ISubModule[]
}

How do I assign values to the mainModules property of the ICompany interface??